# What is the right way to use the native JS methods/calls in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

It's been a long time since I last touched TypeScript, and this time I am not able to override implementations or use the native methods in the `.ts` file.

Those which are highlighted in **red**, except `this` are throwing errors

[image]

I get no autocomplete support from my IDE, also upon compilation there are lots of `TS2304: Cannot find name 'any method or type here'`. And those are supposed to be the "native" methods available in JS. Are there any `@types/type_name` for the basic JS methods?

My `tsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "test"
    ]
}
```

PS: It also tells me to use `T[]` instead of `Array<>`, however, `T[]` also throws `TS2304`

PPS: I also had to completely disable `tslint.json` because then the simple `.join('&')` throws warning that `queryArray` has no implementation for `join`

Comment: Can you please post the code of a [mcve] including the complete module setup? The code in your painting looks like it's part of a `class`.

Answer (score 4):

`tsconfig.json` is missing the lib definitions

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      ...
      "lib": [
        "es2018", // you can pick any es2015, esnext
        "dom" // for DOM relates types
      ]
  }
}
```